# How to format data in specific format

Tags: java

I have a list like this.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataList = [{name=John, age=30}, {name=Alex, age=25}]
```

and I'd like to form JSON like this.

```
[{"header":"name", "value":"John", "idx":"0"}, {"header":"age", "value":"30", "idx":"0"}, {"header":"name", "value":"Alex", "idx":"1"}, {"header":"age", "value":"25", "idx":"1"}]
```

This is what I've tried to form data.

```
int cnt = 0;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> returnList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
for(HashMap<String, String> map: dataList) {
    Iterator i = map.keySet().iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        Object key = i.next();
        HashMap returnMap = new HashMap();
        returnMap.put("header", key);
        returnMap.put("value", map.get(key));
        returnMap.put("idx", cnt);
        returnList.add(returnMap);
    }
    cnt++;
}
```

And then I convert list to JSON.

But I have thounsands of data and it takes too much time to use loop.
Is there any other good ways to shorten time to format list data?

Comment: We have no idea what your `dataList` is, `newmap` is, or what you are actually trying to speed up (is it this loop that is slow? or the JSON converter?)

Comment: Thanks! I edited my question. What I meant was that loop takes time much.

Comment: I don't know about if this will increase performance, but google's gson library does JSON serialization. If you want to write your own like you are now, you can try use a ThreadPoolExecutor to do things in parallel.

Comment: @poiuy Are you sure it is the loop that is taking a lot of time? And not the code exactly after it that converts to JSON? How many items do you have for this to be slow? Can you do a `System.currenttimemillis()`  before the loop, after the loop (before JSON conversion) and after JSON conversion to see how much this slowness really is?

Comment: @poiuy You could also try to change your list implementation from `ArrayList` to `LinkedList` if you have loads of items and maybe your `ArrayList` is resizing too many times.

Comment: @jbx Thank you! I checked it as you said and I realized the loop is not a problem. It took just about 1 sec. The main problem was somewhere else, getting data from database and showing the result on the grid after formatting data into JSON.

Comment: @mckuok Thank you, I will take a look at gson library.